# keystonejs cloudinary invalid signature error

Tags: upload, cloudinary, keystonejs

I have implemented a Cloudinary type in one of my models, but get this error back when I try and save it to Cloudinary:

```
Image upload failed - Invalid Signature              
ea4401c2ebf292208d28f9dc88c5ff1c4e73761d. 
String to sign - 'tags=trial-images_image,trial-    
images_image_55ba9896c6d05b8704802f0a,dev&timestamp=1438292137'.
```

I'm not sure what to do about it, anyone experience this?

Answer (score 1):

You should make sure to calculate the signature correctly. Specifically, you should sign both the tags and the timestamp (including your `api_secret` of course).

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue.
Please double check that you have the configuration parameters(cloud name, api key, api secret) correctly set up. They can be found by going to the management console on your cloudinary account. (Dashboard > Account Details).

**As per their documentation:**
(http://cloudinary.com/documentation/rails_additional_topics#configuration_options)

> Configuration parameters can be globally set using a cloudinary.yml configuration file, located under the config directory of your Rails project. etc...
>
> Here's an example of a cloudinary.yml file:
>
> ```
> production:
>   cloud_name: "sample"
>   api_key: "874837483274837"
>   api_secret: "a676b67565c6767a6767d6767f676fe1"
> ```
>
> etc...
>
> ... Another configuration option is to use a Rails initializer file. You can place a file named cloudinary.rb in the /config/initializers folder of your Rails project. Here's a sample initializer code:
>
> ```
> Cloudinary.config do |config|
>    config.cloud_name = 'sample'
>    config.api_key = '874837483274837'
>    config.api_secret = 'a676b67565c6767a6767d6767f676fe1'
>    config.cdn_subdomain = true 
>  end
> ```
>
> One last configuration option allows you to dynamically configure the Cloudinary library by defining the CLOUDINARY_URL environment variable. The configuration URL is available in the Management Console's dashboard of your account. When using Cloudinary through a PaaS add-on (e.g., Heroku), this environment variable is automatically defined in your deployment environment. Here's a sample value:
>
> `CLOUDINARY_URL=cloudinary://874837483274837:a676b67565c6767a6767d6767f676fe1@sample`

**How I actually solved the issue**

I solved the issue by adopting (and slightly modifying) the first option, which is to create `cloudinary.yml` file in `config` directory and write the following code:

```
(config/cloudinary.yml)

development:
  cloud_name: <%= ENV["CLOUD_NAME"] %>
  api_key: <%= ENV["API_KEY"] %>
  api_secret: <%= ENV["API_SECRET"] %>

test:
  cloud_name: <%= ENV["CLOUD_NAME"] %>
  api_key: <%= ENV["API_KEY"] %>
  api_secret: <%= ENV["API_SECRET"] %>

production:
  cloud_name: <%= ENV["CLOUD_NAME"] %>
  api_key: <%= ENV["API_KEY"] %>
  api_secret: <%= ENV["API_SECRET"] %>
```

Please note that the configuration parameters (cloud name, api key, api secret) are set as environmental variables(`CLOUD_NAME`, `API_KEY`, `API_SECRET`) to prevent them from being exposed when the code is shared publicly. (You don't want to hard code the sensitive information)

You can set environmental variables in bash by editing `.bash_profile` file, which is located (and hidden) in the home directory:

```
(.bash_profile)
.....
export CLOUD_NAME="your cloud name"
export API_KEY="your api key"
export API_SECRET="your api secret"
.....
```

You can check that these environmental variables are correctly set by typing `echo $CLOUD_NAME`, for example, in your terminal.(You may need to quit and restart the terminal). If it's successful, the output will look something like:

```
echo $CLOUD_NAME 
> your cloud name
```

Finally, if you are planning to deploy your app to heroku, you may also want to add cloudinary as an addon, which is free for a starter option, by typing the following command in the terminal:

```
heroku addons:create cloudinary:starter
```

Putting this all together might solve your issue.

Last but not least, I found the following blog post quite useful:

http://www.uberobert.com/rails_cloudinary_carrierwave/

It explains how you can use cloudinary and carrierwave to upload and manipulate the images on your application.

Hope it helps!